# Does from variable in the VueJS router's beforeEach show external URLs or just url local to application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

**router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next)**

I would like to capture the external referring page (page that they were on before clicking a link to my page); I have a SPA VueJS application.

Hard to test without pushing live.

I attempted to use the from variable in the beforeEachEnter  within the component (push it live) and only got a "/" as the form value

Then I thought maybe go to my main.js and get from variable out of:
**router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next)**

Or does anyone know another way to essential get the equivalent of req.header.referer when using VueJS --- let's say I want to display the referring URL to user or send to backend upon submittal of the form created with VueJS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Not bad for a first question, but could you trim it down a bit just to the essentials? And make sure to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Can't you just use `document.referrer`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Using document.referer did not give me what I wanted inside the Vue component but adding it to main.js worked out.  Thanks

Comment: Inside the router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next), I used document.referrer and saved the results in a Vuex state variable .. then from inside component I could access the Vuex state variable.